# Управление Telegram через GUI, или с чего начать, что бы сделать многопоточный спаммер

Tags: python-3.x, gui, proxy

Работаю с Telegram, нужно написать код, который будет многопоточность авторизовываться и писать сообщения через Telegram. СПАМ бот. Работаю на Python, нужно работать с GUI или winAPI, подскажите с чего начать.

Работа 
1) многопоточна
2) Подсовываем прокси для работы с приложением

Comment: Если пишите спамбота - начините с выпивания йада.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: насколько вероятно что спаммер поместит слово СПАМ в вопрос на Stack Overflow и насколько вероятно что очередной соц. эксперимент?

Comment: а почему бы и не попробовать написать. Если это "соц.эксперимент" - то совет в любом случае верный. Хотя не исключаю варианта скрытой рекламы.

Comment: @jfs не нужно пытаться объяснить злым умыслом то, что можно объяснить глупостью :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: верно: «Миром правит не тайная ложа, а явная лажа» и даже если соц. эксперимент, всё равно следует буквально отвечать, см. [Should questions about programming viruses and malware be allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262656/4279)  Первый комментарий был к тому что близко с сердцу не стоит воспринимать.

Answer (score 2):

Желаю всем спамерам побыстрее удавиться и прекратить расходовать ресурсы глобальной сети для своей деятельности.

В Telegram, вообще говоря, предусмотрены некоторые автоматические меры для борьбы с нежелательными рассылками.

1. Получатель сообщения может пожаловаться на корреспондента, если сочтёт нужным. Кнопка "Спам" появляется в верней части диалога, когда кто-то кому-то пишет в первый раз или после большого перерыва в общении.
2. Администратор публичной группы может удалить произвольное сообщение из группового чата, заодно отметив его галкой "Спам".

После получения некоторого* количества независимых жалоб от различных пользователей, аккаунт спамераста блокируется. Вначале на сутки, затем срок блокировки увеличивается, вплоть до "навсегда". Заблокированные аккаунты не могут первыми писать новым незнакомым людям или в публичные группы. Блокировка привязана к номеру телефона.

<sub>* По некоторым данным достаточно двух жалоб.</sub>

Comment: Ответ понятен, и ограничения прекрасно известны! Как работать и какую библиотеку выбрать, к сожалению как и не ясно.